# How to add data in dictionary <dictionary<string,string>,string>

Tags: c#, dictionary

IDK and also can't find a solution on internet for how to add data in inner dictionary.
If I try dic1.Add ("","",""); its invalid. As of two first stringd are not in dictionary format.

Comment: Show some code, at the very least the declaration of `dic1`

Comment: I think you want `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>` with `string` as key.

Comment: *"If I try dic1.Add ("","",""); its invalid"* - That's because nothing in that structure has three strings.  You have two dictionaries.  One has a string as a key and a string as a value.  The other has a dictionary as the key and a string as a value.  (Note: Having a complex type such as a dictionary be a *key* in another dictionary is *very* unusual.)

Comment: Dictionary<dictionary<string,string>,string> = new dictionary<dictionary<string,string>,string>();

Comment: No, i want inner dictionary as key.

Comment: But question is how to add data in inner dictionary.

Comment: @SwairArshad, why do you want inner dictionary as key? How would you access a dictionary value by key, if the key itself is a dictionary. In my humble opinion, that is just bonkers.... ;-)

Comment: @SwairArshad: You'd add data to it like any other dictionary.  First you need a reference to the dictionary you want to add elements to, then you add an element on that reference.  How are you referencing your dictionary?

Comment: OP, take a step back and reevaluate this approach, it ain't a good one. What are your requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per others have said, this is not the right approach.

I would suggest create a class with the information

```
Public Class Thing {
  public string prop1 {get; set;}
  public string prop2 {get; set;}
  public string prop3 {get; set;}
  public Thing(string 1, string 2, string 3) {
    prop1 = 1;
    prop2 = 2;
    prop3 = 3;
   }
}
```

then create a list of the classes.

```
List<Thing> Things = New List<Thing>();
Things.Add (new Thing("one", "two", "three"));
```

then if you want to search for something:

```
Thing foundThing = Things.Where(x => x.prop1 == "Whatever you want to search for").FirstOrDefault();
```

or a new list of things:

```
List<Thing> FilteredListOfThings = Things.Where(x => x.prop1 == "Whatever you want to search for");
```

Answer (score 1):

You would probably need to do something like the following:

```
Dictionary<Dictionary<string, string>, string> a = new Dictionary<Dictionary<string, string>, string>();

a.Add(new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "", "" } }, "");
```

But before you do this, I would ask yourself why you are trying to do this. Remember the KEYS of the dictionary are the first parameter and values are second. You probably don't want to be using dictionaries as a key.

Comment: Okay,  as suggested by all, dropping it for not being a good approach.